# Mono: mkbundle fails to create binary with errors

Tags: c++, mono, embedding, mkbundle

I am experimenting with `mkbundle`
I have a simple `addApp.exe` file which calls a method from `addition.dll`

I am trying to create a binary for `powerpc linux` hardware target. 
I have mono compiled with `eldk-toolchain` for `powerpc` and using the `mkbundle` from that version of mono on target.

I am trying to use `mkbundle` as below

```
mkbundle addApp.exe ./addition.dll --static --deps
```

The output of above command is

```
OS is: Linux

Sources: 2 Auto-dependencies: True

embedding: /home/testAppV2/addApp.exe

embedding: /opt/sdk/mono/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll

embedding: /home/testAppV2/addition.dll

AS = as (default)

[execute cmd]: as -o temp.o temp.s 

Compiling:

CC = cc (default)

[execute cmd]: cc -o 'a.out' -Wall `pkg-config --cflags mono-2` temp.c  `pkg-config --libs-only-L mono-2` -Wl,-Bstatic -lmono-2.0 -Wl,-Bdynamic `pkg-config --libs-only-l mono-2 | sed -e "s/\-lmono-2.0 //"` temp.o

/tmp/cc32Vkrh.o: In function `mono_mkbundle_init':
temp.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `mono_register_bundled_assemblies'

/tmp/cc32Vkrh.o: In function `main':

temp.c:(.text+0x474): undefined reference to `mono_set_dirs'

temp.c:(.text+0x484): undefined reference to `mono_main'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: [Fail] 256
```

I have tried all possible ways to get rid of this error but in vain.
Help needed please